# Currently learning javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, function

#im trying to make it so that the user will have to input an already present login, however i do not know how to actually implement that, when i try using if statements i dont get any response any help appreciated

```
<html>
<head>     
<link href="revision.css" rel= "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login()
{ //start function
alert('the form was submitted')
var user_id = "jack",
password = "password"
} //end function
</script>
<form onsubmit = "login()">
    <p>Enter user ID <input type="text" name="user"></p>
    <p>Enter password <input type="text" name="password"></p>
    <input class = "submit" type="button" name="submit" value="login" onclick="login()"/>
    <p id="text"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you mean like a placeholder?

Comment: Can you add what you've tried with if statements?  Are there any errors you are getting?

Comment: function login()
{ //start function
alert('the form was submitted')
var user_id = "jack";
var password = 1;
if user_id != user:
alert('incorrect user id, please try again')

} //end function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to validate username and password.
To get the value of an input field you need to provide id to input fields.

I think this should work for you.

```
<html>
<head>     
<link href="revision.css" rel= "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login()
{ //start function

var username =document.getElementById("user").value
var password=document.getElementById("pass").value;

if (username=="jack" && password=="password")
{
alert("corrent");
}
else
{
alert("wrong");
}
} //end function
</script>
<form onsubmit = "login()">
    <p>Enter user ID <input type="text" name="user" id="user"></p>
    <p>Enter password <input type="text" name="password" id="pass"></p>
    <input class = "submit" type="button" name="submit" value="login" onclick="login()"/>
    <p id="text"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browsers should take care of that by themselves, as long as you have a form and a submit button.

Per standard, your input button should have `type="submit"` as attribute.

You can also remove your `onclick` attribute on your button.

```
<form onsubmit = "login()">
    <p>Enter user ID <input type="text" name="user"></p>
    <p>Enter password <input type="text" name="password"></p>
    <input class = "submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="login"/>
    <p id="text"></p>
</form>
```

Do note, that your `login()` needs to return true, otherwise nothing will be submitted, and the browser won't store the user login.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code.
you can check this way to the user already exist or not. if the user exist then perform login operation otherwise you can see error user not exist..

```html
<html>
<head>     
<link href="revision.css" rel= "stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login()
{ //start function
   //alert('the form was submitted');
   var user_id = "jack",password = "password";
   var inputUser = document.getElementById('user').value;
   var inputPass = document.getElementById('password').value;
   if(inputUser == user_id && inputPass  == password)
   {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "log in successfully!";
   }
   else
   {
     document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "Invlide User id and password";
   }
} //end function
</script>
<form>
    <p>Enter user ID <input type="text" name="user" id="user"></p>
    <p>Enter password <input type="text" name="password" id="password"></p>
    <input class = "submit" type="button" name="submit" value="login" onclick="login()"/>
    <p id="text"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```